# javascript Runtime error being thrown while using jCarousel

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jcarousel

I'm trying to use the jCarousel and when the page loads it throws this error..

```
JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'jcarousel'
```

and I get brought to this function...

```
(function($) {
$(function() {
    $('[data-jcarousel]').each(function() {
        var el = $(this);
        el.jcarousel(el.data());
    });

    $('[data-jcarousel-control]').each(function() {
        var el = $(this);
        el.jcarouselControl(el.data());
    });
});
})(jQuery);
```

and the error is at the fifth line.

here is my markup...

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="jcarousel-wrapper">
            <div data-jcarousel="true" data-wrap="circular" class="jcarousel">
                <ul>
                    <li><img src="images/1.png" width="600" height="400" alt=""></li>
                    <li><img src="images/2.png" width="600" height="400" alt=""></li>
                    <li><img src="images/3.png" width="600" height="400" alt=""></li>
                    <li><img src="images/4.png" width="600" height="400" alt=""></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <a data-jcarousel-control="true" data-target="-=1" href="#" class="jcarousel-control-prev">&lsaquo;</a>
            <a data-jcarousel-control="true" data-target="+=1" href="#" class="jcarousel-control-next">&rsaquo;</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and here is scripts in my header...

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:3108/code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="jcarousel.data-attributes.js"></script>
```

I have tried just putting the function itself in the header tag and it still throws an error. I have searched for an answer on this and nothing specifically comes up.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm certainly not an expert on jCarousel, but I'm not seeing where you [actually include it](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/reference/installation.html)?

I see something that looks like a plugin for it:

```
<script src="jcarousel.data-attributes.js"></script>
```

But I would expect to see the actual [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/reference/installation.html) script before that:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jcarousel.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE:**

What I mean, is that your full list of scripts needed in order to make this work are:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jcarousel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jcarousel.data-attributes.js"></script>
```

You need to have jQuery included, which you already do. **You also need to have jCarousel included, which you currently do not.** You just need to include that before the data-attributes plugin to make everything work.

Comment: I'm very new to jquery and using plugins, when I downloaded jCarousel it came with examples in it, when I tried running the example that I was going to modify, it won't run because it is saying that jQuery is not defined. So I tried rewriting the example and got the errors I mentioned. All I want to is find a script that I can use to do a simple slideshow with next and prev navigation, I can do this with asp.net but theres a bit of a shake when moving to the next image. jQuery seems to be a lot smoother and not needing a postback

Comment: I added the type of text/javascript but it threw the same error.

Comment: That's not really the issue. You need to ensure that the jCarousel script is included. I'll update the answer to be more clear.

Comment: I see where you are saying, I forgot a crucial part of it. I thought I had it in there.